# Ruby - Match phrase in hash

Tags: ruby

Need to somehow match a phrase in comparison to a hash and grab the id:

Hash:

```
h = [{'id' => '1', 'words' => 'blue table stand'}, {'id' => '2', 'words' => 'red table stand'}]
```

Word:

```
search = 'stand blue'
```

I would like to return the ids of those that has the words 'stand' and 'blue' so that I get back the id number 1. Thanks.

Comment: First of all, your `h` has a smell of wrong approach. You should have something like `{1 => %w[blue table stand], 2 => %w[red table stand]}`. That is much clearer, and will make the rest of the methods more effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @sawa that the data doesn't seem to be formed in the most comfortable manner, but you never know where it came from...

Anyway, this should work:

```
search = "blue stand"
h.select{|x| search.split.all?{|s| x["words"].split.include? s } }.map{|x| x["id"] }

=> ["2"]
```

---

From the comments below, using the [] accessor on the string makes this shorter, and I hate scroll bars enough to update it:

```
h.select{|x| search.split.all?{|s| x["words"][s] } }.map{|x| x["id"] }
```

Comment: A good answer but it's cleaner to use regex: [/blue/,/stand/].all?{|r| r =~ x['words']}

Comment: @pguardiario Actually, you don't need regexes (unless you want to detect the word boundary): `%w[stand blue].all?{|w| x["words"][w]}`

Comment: @sawa that's true you can use string or regex inside [] but I like =~ better.

Comment: @pguardiario cleaner to read, but dynamically generating regexes for whole words is possibly overkill. @sawa - nice shortcut with the `x["words"][w]`, didn't know that one.